# Auth token in URL path

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django REST Framework `TokenAuthentication`.

For a few URLs I'm constrained to having to include the token in the URL path:

`https://example.com/api/<auth_token>/something`

So the urlpatterns are:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/<auth_token>/something', views.SomeView.as_view()),
]
```

And the view is:

```
class SomeView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def get(self, request, auth_token):
    ...
```

But `TokenAuthentication` does not work here because the token is in the URL path, not in the header. I'd like to extend `TokenAuthentication` to handle in-URL tokens too, if possible.

Comment: @RyanWilson Clarified the question with some code.

Comment: Thank you, Andrey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, putting auth tokens in the url is insecure and not recommended (urls end up in server logs and stuff).

If it was a matter of life or death, what I would do is extend the `TokenAuthentication` class from Django rest, overriding only the `authenticate` method. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/acbd9d8222e763c7f9c7dc2de23c430c702e06d4/rest_framework/authentication.py#L174), it obtains the token from the header, runs some validations and calls `self.authenticate_credentials(token)`. So I'd do something like:

```
class UrlTokenAuthentication(TokenAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        token = # get the token from the url path and check that has proper format, etc.
        return self.authenticate_credentials(token)
```